# Defining a relative go-to function - python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

working on a problem in python turtle where i'm required to draw designs inside a square using turtle and placing many of these squares at required co-ordinates.

My current designs use the `goto(x,y)` function however obviously when calling them at different locations the design code is still being called at the original location. is there any way to make a relative-to-square go-to position function or any other workarounds? I understand the basics of turtle however i am still very much a beginner. Cheers

edit: small example of code (works for square drawn at 0,0 however when square is placed at different x,y co-ordinates the text doesn't move with it)

```
pencolor('black')
goto(5, 5)
write('MITSUBISHI', font=('Verdana', '22', 'bold'))
penup()
```

Comment: Please post a minimal working example from your code for better help.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which describes how to format your question so as to be able to receive high-quality answers

Comment: just edited to include snippet of code

Comment: I believe processing has translate, which just moves everything you draw relative to those coords. If you keep track of your own relative coordinates you can mimic this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If the turtle is at position vector (x, y), and you want to move it, say, 3 right and 5 up, you just add that to the coordinates, so the turtle needs to move to `(x + 3, y + 5)`. Luckily, [`turtle.Vec2D`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.Vec2D) supports addition like this, and you can use `goto` on a vector. You can get the current position with [`turtle.pos()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.pos)

```
import turtle

def goto_relative(dx, dy=None):
    """Moves the automatic global turtle by dx and dy (Or a given vector)"""
    goto_relative_on_turtle(turtle, dx, dy)

def goto_relative_on_turtle(t, dx, dy=None):
    """Moves al turtle by dx and dy (Or a given vector)"""
    if dy is None:
        dx, dy = dx
    t.goto(t.pos() + turtle.Vec2D(dx, dy))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Artyer's excellent answer (+1), don't forget about `forward()`, `backward()`, `left()`, `right()` which are all *relative* position operations as opposed to the *absolute* operations `goto()` and `setheading()`.  Making use of the provided relative operations may require a rethink of your graphics.

In a pinch, you can always do something ugly like:

```
t.setx(t.xcor() + 10)
```